# .NET - Child Processes and Configuration Files

Tags: .net, process, windows-services, app-config

I'm designing a windows service which is capable of starting up an arbitrary number of processes, each of which handle data processing on a different set of databases; sandboxes mirroring our live data processing service.  The database connection information is stored in a config file, the location of which is specified in the app.config.  **Is it possible to change app.config data on a per-child-process basis?**

I have my MasterService, which, for instance, starts up 2 new processes: DataProcessor1 and DataProcessor2.  DataProcessor1 should be hitting database `foo_1`, and DataProcessor2 should be hitting database `foo_2`.  However, by default the database configuration is set to `data_service` so that the MasterService can access what it needs to function independent of what its children are doing.

As I mentioned previously, the location of the database configuration is specified in the app.config.  **Is there a way for me to programmatically give each processes its own app.config, or change the app.config data on a per-process basis, so I can point each process at its own unique database configuration?**

Our core libraries depend heavily on the data config setup we currently have, so changing it is rather out of the question.  Likewise, injecting a custom db connection object is also not possible at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Does the child process have to get it's connection string from the app.config? If not could you possibly just pass the connection string as a command line argument to the child process.

I believe you could use the ConfigurationManager class in System.Configuration to make runtime changes to the app.config, not sure if you can use it to change the path of the app.config to another file though.

Comment: The app.config doesn't supply the connection string, only a path to a data config that provides it.  Now, I may be able to generate a new data config per process, save it to disk, pass that new path as a command line arg, and possibly coerce the code to load the data config at the provided path.  That's probably the best shot I have.